# How to use Sfdc.ChatterNotes.createNote() in my visualforce page to add a Note to my custom object?

Tags: visualforce, chatter, childrelationship, contentnote

I'm trying to have a button in my VFP that'll add a Note (AttachedContentNote) to my custom object.

I want my button to do the same as the New Note button from the Note's relatedList in my custom object Salesforce default page. (I'm not talking about notes and attachment)
[image: This New Note button]

This button is using this code onclick:

```
Sfdc.ChatterNotes.createNote();
```

I've included these js files (Don't even know if I do it right??? Is there a best practise on this?):

```
<script src="/EXT/ext-3.0.0/ext-core.js"/>
<script src="/jslibrary/1487809120000/sfdc/Chatter.js"/>
<script defer="true" src="/jslibrary/1487809120000/sfdc/ChatterDefer.js"/>
```

When I click on my button that calls the Sfdc...createNote(). I get a popup that says: "The action you performed was invalid for your session. Please refresh your page and try again."
[image: Alert message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it!
Instead of trying to do it client-side in javascript. I do it server-side in Apex like that:

```
ContentNote cn = new ContentNote();
cn.title = 'Untitled Note';
insert(cn);

ContentDocumentLink link = new ContentDocumentLink();
link.ContentDocumentId = cn.Id;
link.LinkedEntityId = ***myCustomObjectId***;
link.ShareType = 'I'; 
insert(link);
```

Et voilà!